# How exactily does the 'output channel' size work in nn.conv2d filter?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm studying pytorch convolution filter Conv2d function.
And I found the kernel of  conv2d(3,3,3) ((meaning input channel = 3, output channel =3, kernel size = 3)) is the tensor of [3,3,3,3], just like below. And I dont' understand what is the use of this huge tensor.
I can understand easily the kernel of conv2d(3,1,3) ((tensor [1,3,3,3])). It has amount 3 of 3*3 matrix. And maybe each matrix is applyed to R G B matrixes of input image. And it would be merged into one matrix for grayscaling, so the output channel is one. simple.

But what is good for [3,3,3,3]????  Isn't it still enough for 3 of 3*3 matrix  to apply to R G B matrix and output them without merging? Why do we need extra 2 more 3,3,3 tensor??

I'll specify the problem.
First, Let's say conv2d(3,1,3) as   3 input channel (I1, I2, I3) and 3 kernel (K1, K2, K3) and one output channel (O1).
Calculation is like this.

```
(I1*K1 + I2*K2 + I3*K3) /3 = O1.
```

Maybe if I want 3 outputs, the calculation would be like this

```
I1*K1 = O1     
I2*K2 = O2
I3*K3 = O3
```

But reallity is complicated. Because if we need 3 output channels, the kernels amount is 9.
Conv2d(3,3,3) represents 3 input (I1, I2, I3). And 9 kernels (K11, K12, K13, K21, K22, K23, K31, K32, K33).
Then What is the calculation pair??

following is the 9 kernels of conv2d(3,3,3) situation.

```
conv2d(3,3,3)
=>3,3,3,3  kernel
=>tensor([[[[-0.0904, -0.0924, -0.0892],
          [-0.0060, -0.0389, -0.1388],
          [ 0.1636, -0.0933, -0.0295]],

         [[-0.0742,  0.0426, -0.0662],
          [ 0.1625, -0.1485, -0.0169],
          [-0.1122, -0.0875,  0.1021]],

         [[ 0.1214, -0.0896,  0.1304],
          [ 0.0612,  0.0367, -0.0288],
          [-0.1868, -0.1356,  0.0869]]],


        [[[ 0.0792, -0.1562, -0.1878],
          [ 0.0373,  0.1162,  0.1224],
          [-0.1138,  0.0553,  0.1449]],

         [[ 0.1558, -0.1661, -0.0963],
          [ 0.0603, -0.1405,  0.0995],
          [-0.0644, -0.1151,  0.1422]],

         [[ 0.1534,  0.0399, -0.1709],
          [ 0.0765, -0.0665,  0.0119],
          [ 0.0586,  0.1424, -0.1755]]],


        [[[-0.0199, -0.0956, -0.0577],
          [ 0.1312, -0.0273,  0.0615],
          [-0.1037, -0.0247,  0.1915]],

         [[-0.1297,  0.0451,  0.0360],
          [-0.0462,  0.1846, -0.1615],
          [-0.0642,  0.0324,  0.1428]],

         [[ 0.1254, -0.0323,  0.1129],
          [ 0.0482,  0.0839,  0.0227],
          [ 0.0845,  0.1773, -0.1706]]]], requires_grad=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the Conv2d operation as follows:

You take the matrix inner product between a `(C_in, K_H, K_W)` block within your input tensor and your filter of the same size, i.e. (C_in, K_H, K_W) to get one entry of your output tensor. Since you have `C_out` (out_channels) number of channels for each spatial location in the output tensor, you have to create `C_out` different `(C_in, K_H, K_W)` filters accordingly, which results in a stacked filter shape of `(C_out, C_in, K_H, K_W)`.

Notation:

- C_in: in_channels
- K_H: kernel height
- K_W: kernel width

Comment: I still dont understand....   Let's say input channel  I1 I2 I3  , and  9 kernel  K11 K12 K13 K21 K22 K23 K31 K32 K33.    Then which pairs are caculated??

Comment: It is just like fully-connected layer for 1d data. Suppose we now have a tensor shape of (B, C_in, K_H, K_W). What conv2d does is essentially: 1. flatten the tensor to (B, C_in\*K_H\*K_W):=(B, D) 2. perform standard matrix multiplication with the flattened filter (D, C_out), where D=C_in\*K_H\*K_W.

Comment: I'm focusing on 'convolution filtering', before flattening and others. What's happening between 3 inputs and 9 kernels?

Comment: Conv2d(3,3,3) is 3 (3,3,3) filters instead of 9 (3,3) filters. Each (3,3,3) filter is elementwisely multiplied by a (3,3,3) region of your RGB image, where the leading dimension is your color channels.